# IIS impersonation returns app pool user Service account

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have developed one MVC application and hosted in server. I used Service Account as app pool identity and provided full access(SysAdmin) on database to that Service Account only.  Below are my configurations in Web.config & coding.
Web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
 <identity impersonate="false"/>
```

In my Data Access layer I'm using below coding to get windows identity :

```
 string windowsLogin = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString();
```

Now my issue is, when I'm accessing my application it is taking app pool Identity instead of Windows identity.

if I set the identity in Web.config to impersonate="true" I'm able to get windows login but the communication between application and database happening with my windows login instead of app pool identity (service account).
How can I get the identity of the user accessing the application and not the IIS APPPOOL user?

Comment: It's unclear exactly what kind of impersonation and identity you are trying to achieve here.  identity impersonate controls the identity upon which the IIS worker process runs as.  This is not typically what most people want.  They simply want the HttpContext.Current.User.Identity to be correct.  Do you actually want the worker process to run as the current user?

Comment: It is basically intranet application and I don't want to explicitly provide the database access to each and every user, so that I have created one service account and provided full permissions for that. When user hits my application it should take his windows login name and displays on my UI and all the CURD operation should happen using service account only.

Comment: Then you don't want Impersonation.  Instead, specify your apps user name in the app pool properties.  Keep Windows authentication though, just remove impersonation.

Comment: Yes, I did the same. I updated the web.config to <identity impersonate="false"/> but still getting same issue.

Comment: You want to make sure that authentication is occurring.. check the IsAuthenticated value to make sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Issue got resolved with below settings.

Created app pool and run it as with service account and configure it to web site in IIS.

In My Code File:

```
string windowsLogin = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"].ToString();
```

In Web.config file:

```
<authentication mode="Windows">     
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />

</authorization>
<identity impersonate="false" />
```

Note: It will give you an error if you run from Visual Studio IDE. If you publish and run it from IIS it will work.

Comment: "run it as with service account", what do you mean? Thanks